# awk help: replace 4th octet in IP address with a different IP in csv spreadsheet

Tags: replace, sed, awk, ip

I'd like to make a simple awk script/one-liner that will go through a csv file and help me replace the 4th octet in an ip Address, with a value in the 2nd column. Here's what the initial input would look like:

> 10.4.0.**0** 2
>   10.4.50.**0** 4
>   10.4.15.**0** 52
>   10.4.0.**0** 19

I'd like

> 10.4.0.**2**
>   10.4.50.**4**
>   10.4.15.**52**
>   10.4.0.**19**

Comment: Okay, now to add a little bit more complexity. Lets say there's a specific sheet involved on this spreadsheet that we need to pull data from, as well as fields before the ip address that are not delimited with a period.  Here's a screenshot. http://www.tiikoni.com/tis/view/?id=c600549

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it briefly, and a bit obscurely like this:

```
awk '{$4=$5} NF--' FS='[ .]+' OFS=. file.csv
```

#### Explanation

- `$4=$5` sets the fourth octet to the fifth field, where field counting is based on dots and space.
- `NF--` has two functions, it removes the fifth field (`$5`) and invokes the default rule (`{print $0}`) because it is non-zero.

#### Update

The request by the OP posted as a comment (append the netmask to the ip address) can easily be added to this answer:

```
awk '{$4=$5"/28"} NF--' FS='[ .]+' OFS=. file.csv
```

Output:

```
10.4.0.2/28
10.4.50.4/28
10.4.15.52/28
10.4.0.19/28
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do it like this:

```
 awk -F'[ .]' '{print $1 "." $2 "." $3 "." $5}' file.csv
```

Comment: Awesome that worked! now to take it one step further, how would i add /28  at the end ? so the output would look like 10.4.0.2/28

Comment: `awk -F'[ .]' '{print $1 "." $2 "." $3 "." $5 "/28"}' file.csv`